# Does Pandas concat interpolate missing values in multivariate time series?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, time-series

## QUESTION (solved)

Why using (Python Pandas) `pandas.concat(dfList)` interpolates some of my values?
I am getting `events` from the following code that returns a list of DataFrame separated by any NaN values.

```
# src: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402384/how-to-split-a-pandas-time-series-by-nan-values
events = np.split(df, np.where(np.isnan(df['variable13']))[0])
events = [ev[~np.isnan(ev.variable13)] for ev in events if not isinstance(ev, np.ndarray)] # removing NaN entries
events = [ev for ev in events if not ev.empty] # removing empty DataFrames
# 'events' is a list with the events separated by the NaN values.


trimmedDfList = events 
trimmedDf = pd.concat(trimmedDfList)

print "aaaaaa"
print df.isnull().sum()
print "bbbbb"
print trimmedDf.isnull().sum()

# plot
df.plot(subplots=True)
trimmedDf.plot(subplots=True)
plt.show()
```

gives me the following output and plots:

```
aaaaaa
variable1   13780
variable2   13780
variable3   13780
variable4   13780
variable5   13780
variable6   13780
variable7   13780
variable8   13780
variable9   13780
variable10  13780
variable11  13780
variable12  13780
variable13  12969
variable14  12969
variable15  12969
variable16  12969
variable17  12969
variable18  12969
dtype: int64

bbbbb
variable1   811
variable2   811
variable3   811
variable4   811
variable5   811
variable6   811
variable7   811
variable8   811
variable9   811
variable10  811
variable11  811
variable12  811
variable13  0
variable14  0
variable15  0
variable16  0
variable17  0
variable18  0
dtype: int64
```

[image]
[image]

The highlighted interpolation is unwanted, how can I avoid it?  I just want fill the gaps with NaNs.

## SOLVED:

Finally, `trimmedDf` DataFrame (second figure plot) is not actually interpolated. The point is: `df` has indexes with NaN values, meanwhile `trimmedDf` has no indexes in highlighted gaps... that's why the `pd.plot()` shows an interpolation.

I then used `trimmedDf = trimmedDf.resample('1s').fillna(0)`.

Comment: it's totally legal to answer your own questions, and accept the answer, hereby notifying everyone that you think the question is too good to be deleted, and that an answer has been found by you after posting.

Comment: ok should I now move the SOLVED part into a new answer?

Comment: its not required, I would do that, and others woulld argue its bad form, but you may want to read this discussion on behaviour on the forum.. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296938/i-asked-a-question-should-i-accept-my-own-answer-or-someone-elses?cb=1

Comment: It's best to either delete the question (if you think it is not of much value to others) or create and accept your own answer (if you think it could be of value).  @Henrik -- that meta discussion concerns cases with more than one answer.  If there is only only one answer and it's by the author, there is no ambiguity.

Comment: FWIW, I would err here on the side of answering and accepting your own question (vs deleting) as there are (at the moment) 23 views and some of them may be curious as to the resolution.

Comment: 32 views now... it's not me so I'll leave the question here